# Is it possible to use xshift and a variable to place several (different) paths

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to use xshift and a variable to place several (different) paths with variable equidistance. I want to configure the space between the paths so giving a variable e.g. to xshift in scope would do the trick.
Unfortunately I cannot use foreach since the paths are different.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[node distance =4.5cm,thick]

\newcommand{\room} {
 \coordinate (a) at  (0,0) ;
 \coordinate (b) at (5,0);
 \coordinate (c) at  (5,5);
 \coordinate (d) at (0,4);
 \coordinate (e) at (1,3);
 \coordinate (f) at     (1.4,3) ;
 \coordinate (g) at (1.4,2.6)   ;
 \coordinate (h) at (1,2.6) ;
 \coordinate (i) at (1,3)   ;
}


\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-7cm]
    \room;
    \draw[dashed,thick] (b)--(c)--(d)--(e)--(f);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=-7cm]
    \room;
    \draw[dashed,thick] (b)--(c)--(d)--(e)--(f) --(g) --(h);
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[xshift=12cm,yshift=-7cm]  
    \room;
    \draw[densely dotted,very thick] (d)--(e)--(f) --(g) --(h)--(e);
    \draw[dashed,thick] (b)--(c)--(d);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Added Eaxmple

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (or at least an image) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of having understood well what you are asking for, but you can define an initial `lenght` and then use this.

For example, I reproduced your picture three times, with the same code, by changing this `length`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,calc}

\newlength\mydistance % definition
\setlength{\mydistance}{5cm} % first setting

\newcommand{\room} {
 \coordinate (a) at  (0,0) ;
 \coordinate (b) at (5,0);
 \coordinate (c) at  (5,5);
 \coordinate (d) at (0,4);
 \coordinate (e) at (1,3);
 \coordinate (f) at     (1.4,3) ;
 \coordinate (g) at (1.4,2.6)   ;
 \coordinate (h) at (1,2.6) ;
 \coordinate (i) at (1,3)   ;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-7cm]
    \room;
    \draw[dashed,thick] (b)--(c)--(d)--(e)--(f);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=\mydistance,yshift=-7cm]
    \room;
    \draw[dashed,thick] (b)--(c)--(d)--(e)--(f) --(g) --(h);
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[xshift=2\mydistance,yshift=-7cm]  
    \room;
    \draw[densely dotted,very thick,] (d)--(e)--(f) --(g) --(h)--(e);
    \draw[dashed,thick] (b)--(c)--(d);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{2cm}
\setlength{\mydistance}{5.5cm} % re-set the distance

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-7cm]
    \room;
    \draw[dashed,thick] (b)--(c)--(d)--(e)--(f);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=\mydistance,yshift=-7cm]
    \room;
    \draw[dashed,thick] (b)--(c)--(d)--(e)--(f) --(g) --(h);
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[xshift=2\mydistance,yshift=-7cm]  
    \room;
    \draw[densely dotted,very thick,] (d)--(e)--(f) --(g) --(h)--(e);
    \draw[dashed,thick] (b)--(c)--(d);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace*{2cm}
\setlength{\mydistance}{7cm} % changed again the distance

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=-7cm]
    \room;
    \draw[dashed,thick] (b)--(c)--(d)--(e)--(f);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=\mydistance,yshift=-7cm]
    \room;
    \draw[dashed,thick] (b)--(c)--(d)--(e)--(f) --(g) --(h);
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[xshift=2\mydistance,yshift=-7cm]  
    \room;
    \draw[densely dotted,very thick,] (d)--(e)--(f) --(g) --(h)--(e);
    \draw[dashed,thick] (b)--(c)--(d);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives you:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for but I did not find it in the pgfmanual.